# Where do my interests lie?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verb-agreement

Would I write that ‘my interests lies with…’, or would I write ‘my interests lies in…?’ If it’s the latter, should my interests lie within vs. in?

I do not need instruction on using lay or lie.

Ex.
After you lie down, I will lay a blanket on top of you.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187784/correct-use-of-lie-or-lay-in-the-following-context

Comment: I see more "in" than "with" https://www.google.com/search?q=%22my+interests+lies+with%22+OR+%22my+interests+lies+in%22

Comment: How are you planning to complete the sentence? I think it might vary depending on that: whether it's a subject, a person, a group, a topic; whether it's broad and general, or narrow and specific; and whether your interests are exactly aligned or more in the general direction of. "with" would be less specific than "in".

Comment: I'd use *in* if I was set on *interests lie*. But a cover letter is a sales tool for juicing up my story. My interests in writing don't lie in or around anywhere, they ... excite me, charge me up, spark my enthusiasm. Spin? Hype? A tad, but marketing is defined as ever so intrusive yet still welcome.

Comment: I'd say _My interests lie_ rather than _lies_.